# What are the limitations of using Word [Quick] Style Sets?

Tags: microsoft-word

There are 4 custom style sets that used in my organization. I notice that Table Styles are not applied through style sets. I also have several users reporting that numbering breaks after applying a style set. It's behaving as if the List Styles are not applied.

What are the limitations of using Style Sets?

Answer (score 0):

*As answered in the [Microsoft Answers forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/what-are-the-limitations-of-using-word-quick-style/cf729468-48c3-4f6a-b960-b45078a0e10b).*

> Hi Matt,
>
> First, see my analysis of [[Quick] Style Sets](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#quick_style_set).
>
> There is much more there than I care to write here.
>
> - Only styles that are in the Quick Style Gallery are included in [Quick] Style Sets.
> - Table Styles are not included.
> - List Styles are not included. Further, if your multilevel list is applied to paragraph style that are in  the [Quick] Style Set, the
>   numbering may still break. See:
>
> 1. [A Global StyleSheet in Microsoft Word?](http://www.addbalance.com/word/stylesheet.htm) and the example
> 2. [Outline Heading Styles Global Stylesheet Add-In](http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#GlobalStylesheet)
>
> The best way to have numbering for new documents is likely to have
> document templates, perhaps Workgroup Templates that already contain
> the numbering, set up following the directions in [How to create
> numbered headings or outline numbering in Ribbon Versions of Word by
> Shauna Kelly](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html).
>
> The Add-In copies numbered paragraph styles so set up in a multilevel
> list without copying the multilevel list, itself. It copies them using
> the Organizer and copies them three times in order to maintain the
> linkages.
>
> For Tables, you may be able to use [Quick Tables](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/tables.htm#QuickTables) which are Building
> Blocks. It is not the same as applying a table style, but may allow some uniformity.
>
> When working with these tools, remember to use [Theme](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Themes) Colors (and
> fonts). That will allow you to quickly change looks.

*Links, other than the one to the parallel answer and the one to Shauna Kelly's page, are to my website.*

Please review this [link on cross-posting etiquette](http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184) and follow that advice.

*I modified your question title to specify that these are Quick Style Sets. This helps us remember some of their limitations.*